# Firebase check if database exists

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database of form: https://imgur.com/ar8A3DN

I would like two functions:
1. `refExists`, check if any child exists in database. So that

```
refExists('datasets') = true
refExists('foo') = false
```

2. `createChild` that creates a new child.

My firebase database instance is declared via:

```
const accountKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
const accountKey     = require(accountKeyPath);
const firebaseAdmin  = admin.initializeApp(accountKey);
const dbRef          = firebaseAdmin.database().ref('datasets');
```

The interesting thing is that dbRef and this code which should return an error:

```
const badRef = firebaseAdmin.database().ref('foo')
```

both output the same thing. So it's unclear how to check the existence of `foo` when `ref('datasets')` and `ref('foo')` behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The way to check whether an element exists is by trying to retrieve a snapshot of it - if the snapshot returns null then the element does not exist.

Adding elements is as simple as calling `set` on the desired element path with a data object.

```
function refExists(path) {
  firebaseAdmin.database().child(path).once('value', (snap) => {
    if (snap.val() !== null) {
        console.log('ref exists');
    }
  });
}

function addRef(newPath, data) {
  firebaseAdmin.database().child(newPath).set(data);
}
```